# package ‘rsgcc’ not installed because it is not built for UCRT

Tags: r

In R I am facing the following error during the installation of "rsgcc" package.

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/Drabd/Downloads/rsgcc_1.0.6.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")
package ‘rsgcc’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : package ‘rsgcc’ not installed because it is not built for UCRT
```

Could you please help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

What version of R are you using? With a stable R build (v 4.1.0) downloaded and installed (core files + 32 or 64 bit), R will most likely unpack rsgcc_1.0.6.zip and unblock the UCRT issue. https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.1.0/R-4.1.0-win.exe